# Excel 2016 userform macros, Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

I have created a User form in Excel 2016 that contains several combo boxes, several text boxes, two radio buttons, and a submit button.  First, how do I get the combo boxes to reference a list that I already have set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fire an event using the form_activate event handler. Right click on your userform in the project window and click "View Code"

Paste something of this nature into the code window:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    ComboBox1.AddItem ("1")
    ComboBox1.AddItem ("2")
    ComboBox1.AddItem ("3")
End Sub
```

This will load items to the combobox. You can also change it to something like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    ComboBox1.AddItem (range("'Sheet1'!A1").value)
    ComboBox1.AddItem (range("'Sheet1'!A2").value)
End Sub
```

if your combobox items are on the excel sheet somewhere.

Once the Activate event is created, you need something that opens the form in the first place (which I am sure you already have figured out). So something like this:

```
Public Sub show_form()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

then you would call the event show_form by a button or something on the excel sheet.

**Full Example**

Here is a full example:

Create a new workbook. Put some data in A1 and A2. Keep the default sheet name of "Sheet1"

Press Alt F11 to open the VBA side. click Insert > UserForm

UserForm1 appears. Right click on it and click View Code. Paste this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    ComboBox1.AddItem (Range("'Sheet1'!A1").Value)
    ComboBox1.AddItem (Range("'Sheet1'!A2").Value)
End Sub
```

Double click on ThisWorkBook in the tree. Click Insert > Module. Paste this:

```
Public Sub show_form()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Your tree should look like this:

[image]

Now in the excel workbook, add a shape like a box. Right click on your shape and click Assign Macro. Select show_form.

Now try running in. Click the shape you had. This should show the form. When you click on the dropdown it should have two items populated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60849/discussion-on-answer-by-eric-f-excel-2016-userform-macros-windows-7).

Comment: @DavidPostill We should be good now. We can delete all the many comments. BTW am I as an answer provider able to start the chat or does someone with more privilege have to initiate it?

Comment: It happens automatically after a certain number of comments between the OP and another user - I'm not sure how many - or a mod can do it at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example:

Create a new workbook. Put some data in A1 and A2. Keep the default sheet name of "Sheet1"

Press Alt F11 to open the VBA side. click Insert > UserForm

UserForm1 appears. Right click on it and click View Code. Paste this:

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    ComboBox1.AddItem (Range("'Sheet1'!A1").Value)
    ComboBox1.AddItem (Range("'Sheet1'!A2").Value)
End Sub
Double click on ThisWorkBook in the tree. Click Insert > Module. Paste this:

Public Sub show_form()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub